# Display a variable while rendering SDL_TTF text C++

Tags: c++, sdl

Need to print out a global varible in C++ using TTF render text. So it would show like this:

"Total Killed: " *Varible Here*

Got this it works but it pushs the text to the left

```
SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font, "Humans killed: " + totalKilled,    foregroundColor, backgroundColor);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "pushing the text to the left"? Please detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the type of `totalKilled`?  `int`?

Answer (score 1):

```
"Humans killed: " + totalKilled
```

This is pointer arithmetic.  It ***does not*** convert `totalKilled` to a `std::string`, concatenate that onto `"Humans killed: "`, and convert the result to a null-terminated string.

Try this instead:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template< typename T >
std::string ToString( const T& var )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << var;
    return var.str();
}

...

SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded
    (
    font, 
    ( std::string( "Humans killed: " ) + ToString( totalKilled ) ).c_str(),
    foregroundColor, 
    backgroundColor
    );
```

If you're willing to use Boost you can use [`lexical_cast<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) instead of `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using c++ 11, you can use std::to_string().

```
std::string caption_str = "Humans killed: " + std::to_string(totalKilled)

SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font, caption_str.c_str(),    foregroundColor, backgroundColor);
```